# Delphi with HTML/CSS interface

Tags: html, delphi, interface

I want to develop a delphi application with an HTML/CSS graphical user interface, not necessarily running from within a web browser. I want to do this do create a richer graphical user interface with animations etc. and break away from normal VCL components / Windows look. Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't expect CSS + HTML to bring a richer user interface than a native windows application where you can take advantage of the GPU, ... Have you looked at .NET and WPF (http://windowsclient.net/)? There are free developer tools that might get you started.

Comment: do you know Intraweb? if i'm remembering well it comes free from delphi7.

best regards,
Radu

Comment: As of the release of RAD Studio XE2, you can now use Firemonkey for rich HD applications. However Firemonkey is still very raw and premature, so I wouldn't necessarily recommend it quite yet, but it has high potential for XE3 for Windows 8...

Comment: And even if you don't go to Firemonkey, XE2's Delphi now can compile 64 apps, and you can also implement VCL styles like I'm doing in some of my projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In one of my applications I have an an embedded browser and I have implemented the IDocHostUIHandler interface.  This allows me to expose a COM object via the "GetExternal" method.  I simply have a COM object that exposes methods and properties of my application which makes them available to the web pages hosted inside the embedded browser.

So the script in my web pages has lines like "external.DoSomething()" and "i=external.GetThisValue()".  So, for example, behind button onclick events you can run a method of your application (implement in the main form, in the COM object itself, or whatever you like).

This site has lots of info on embedding a browser in your Delphi app:
http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22

It can certainly be cumbersome to implement a lot of this stuff and in many cases there are probably better options.  But for my specific purpose I am able to offer a "home page" which can easily be modified to change its layout, look and even expose more (or less) functionality as required by myself or my users.

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the great responses!! You have given me lots of options to explore. I think for what I am trying to accomplish Jenakai's answer is my best bet. Again thanks to everyone. This site is absolutely great!

Answer (score 9):

HTML and CSS won't deliver animations or a Rich User Interface to your feet.  Far from it in fact.  Quite the opposite.  You will need to invest in a toolkit to provide that sort of functionality and almost certainly involve JavaScript.  And even if you don't want your eventual application hosted in a web browser, your application will itself have to host a web browser to render your HTML/CSS/JavaScript UI, and you will then have a much more difficult job of connecting your GUI to your application logic (unless you do actually embrace a web application architecture).

Delphi (or any Windows application development language for that matter) gets you much, **much** further  down the road towards a more simply, effectively and quickly implemented Rich User Interface than HTML or CSS.

If you don't like the look and feel of the standard Delphi controls (which in essence is what you are saying) there are numerous alternative libraries available.

Also bear in mind however that when someone uses a Windows application they expect it to look and behave a certain way to a large extent.  Using fancy, web based paradigm's in a desktop application simply for the sake of it is likely to confuse and frustrate users if taken too far.

I'm all for user interfaces breaking with convention where it leads to a more intuitive user interface, but simply being "prettier" does not necessarily lead in that direction and is just as misguided as dogmatically adhering to convention.

Comment: While I won't argue with this answers meaning back in 2010, now, in 2015, this answer is no longer relevant. The advancement of HTML5, CSS3 and frameworks like AngularJS (and components like BootstrapUI) and their performance make them very viable candidates for integration in Delphi applications.

Comment: @Peter - I guess that's why answers (and questions) have the date/time clearly visible.  ;)  Retro-editing all content on SO for continued relevance is impractical.  Consumers of the content will simply have to apply some common sense I fear.  Of course in this particular case Delphi itself has moved on significantly.  With FMX (love it or hate it) the things the OP asked for (animation, non-VCL look etc) are all more readily within their grasp without having to reach for HTML. :)

Comment: I perfectly agree with you. And yes, Delphi has come a long way, in terms of UI and ease of use, but I believe some people will still look to integrate web components (like AngularJS or EmberJS).  I just felt the need to point out that anyone looking for an up-to-date answer to OP's question may need to look beyond.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a Delphi program with a better-looking interface, HTML is *really* not what you're looking for.  What you really need are better-looking VCL controls.

Take a look at TMS Smooth Controls, for example.  If you're on Delphi 2009 or 2010, you can get it as a free download [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/reg/delphi).  That's one of many component libraries that can bring a slicker user interface to your program.

Answer (score 4):

HTML / CSS offers some nice features which are (not yet?) available in Delphi and the VCL. They are also a good starting point for client/server programming, separating the user interface and the business logic is a key factor here.

One popular library for Delphi is the [extpascal project](http://code.google.com/p/extpascal/):

> ExtPascal is an Object Pascal (Delphi,
>   FreePascal/Lazarus) wrapper/binding
>   for Ext JS, a complete GUI Ajax
>   framework, made in JavaScript, for
>   Rich Internet Application (RIA)
>   development. ExtPascal lets you use
>   Ext JS from Object Pascal commands
>   issued by the server. It brings the
>   structure and strict syntax of the
>   Object Pascal for programming the web
>   browser. ExtPascal will wrap Draw2d 
>   into future releases.

Some demos are online [here](http://extpascal.call.inf.br/cgi-bin/extpascalsamples.cgi) and [here](http://extpascal.call.inf.br/cgi-bin/fishfacts.cgi).

p.s. and I really like the HTML / CSS support for element and font sizes in relative units (for exampe percent). Combined with browser zoom in / zoom out and [WCAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines), user interface ergonomy can not be much better.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML Option 1

If you relly want to use HTML+CSS(+JavaScript) to build a GUI, you can have a look at [HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(VS.85).aspx), a very fascinating concept from Microsoft. HTML Applications, .hta files, have been supported from Windows ME, if I remember correctly, and they are still supported on Windows 7.

You could create an HTML Application (i.e. an HTA file), and by so doing, creating a GUI using only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. When the user double-clicks the HTA file, it will open like a program, but the GUI is entirely based on HTML; in fact, the entire Window is an Internet Explorer window in disguise.

And now comes the important part: you could create non-GUI Delphi applications (i.e., Delphi applications that are not console applications, but that have no forms either), and start them via hyperlinks (or JavaScript) from within your HTA GUI. (Well, it is probably better to create one such Delphi application, and use command-line arguments (`ParamStr`s) to communicate the desired action.)

Just an idea...

## HTML Option 2

Alternatively, you could create a normal Delphi GUI application, but fill the entire main form with a TWebBrowser (a IE control), using `Align := alClient`. Then you could either load static HTML pages (stored in the Program Files folder or on the Internet), or you could use Delphi to dynamically create HTML pages to show. I think it is possible to intercept links from the control, so that you could respond to links using Delphi code.

## What about OpenGL?

If you want to "break away" from the normal Windows look and feel, then I would recommend you to create your GUI using OpenGL. It is very easy to make a Delphi application with OpenGL (as long as you are familiar with OpenGL) - just add "OpenGL" to your `uses` list.

Answer (score 1):

First this: I completely agree with Deltics' answer.

Having said that, if you master HTML and CSS (and JavaScript and AJAX etc etc) and you are looking for a way to use the power and speed of the Delphi compiler to run the dynamics of a website, this may be of interest.

I've created a project that uses the Delphi compiler to build a library that runs a website. The source-files combines HTML and Delphi, much like other web-scripting tools out there, but gets processed on a page-refresh, and compiled automatically. It uses a 'library handler' that plugs in the website library into pretty much anything you like: IIS, Apache, a stand-alone HTTP server (for hosting), or directly into InternetExplorer or FireFox (which is great for developing).

http://xxm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

New versions of Qt contain ability to use html/js for interfaces. I don't know if there is Qt library  bindings for Delphi, but Qt is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

for Rich GUI and animation, have you looked at KSDev [DXScen](http://www.ksdev.com/dxscene/index.html) and [VGScene](http://www.ksdev.com/vgscene/index.html) ?

Comment: Now it is called a FireMonkey, and is a part of Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your delphi/Pascal Object 'background' and have a Web like RIA you also have a look to Morfik : [link text](http://www.morfik.com/)

Comment: Morfik requires a server, and you know it.

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden Strange comment ! The question did'nt say 'without server' and my answer was just for 'open' the minds. So, I am not a Morfik specialist but it seems to be solutions to deploy 'without server' : http://wiki.morfik.com/wiki3/Deployment_on_Windows#Stand-alone-xapp

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden Yes, seems promising !